# Возникновение сигнала SIGPIPE (ошибка EPIPE) при обращении из браузера Android устройства

Tags: c++, android, сокет, http, tcp-ip

Написал демон на С++ (Линукс). Он слушает запросы от устройства на Android.

Причем сделал универсально: в браузере на Android в адресной строке указывается IP-адрес/сайт (на котором слушает демон), и сам демон посылает в ответ файл, который сохраняется в браузере.

Использую неблокирующие сокеты, TCP и т.д.

Спустя некоторое время после начала отправки файла приходит ошибка EPIPE (`errno = 32 - Broken pipe`). После этой ошибки я закрываю сокет.

Не знаю как будет работать на других Android телефонах, но мой делает повторный запрос и скачивает файл со второго раза без ошибки EPIPE. Боюсь, что на других телефонах файл просто не скачается.

Если я проделываю то же самое со своего компьютера, то никаких ошибок EPIPE не возникает.

Хотелось бы разобраться почему так происходит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался... Потратил кучу времени, чтобы выяснить - просто так на моём китайском телефоне (хотя вроде хуавей хвалят) работает браузер...

> в нете попадается информация, что стандартный загрузчик на Андроиде
>   (особенно ниже 3.х) с ошибками скачивает файлы, и предлагается
>   установить альтернативный браузер со встроенным менеджером загрузок,
>   может Вам тоже этот подход попробовать? –  margosh

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка EPIPE возвращается обычно в том случае, если данный сокет никем не читается, тоесть нет ни одного процесса, имеющего открытый на чтение дескриптор, связанный с этим сокетом.

Возможна ситуация, что Ваш клиент на Андроид по каким-то причинам закрыл дескриптор на чтение, связанный с этим сокетом, тогда, по идее, Вы должны были бы в демоне получить сигнал SIGPIPE и как-то обработать эту ситуацию.
Если же вы игнорируете SIGPIPE, то вызов *write()* обязан вернуть вам EPIPE.

Comment: Точнее write вернет -1 и переменная errno будет установлена в EPIPE. И пожалуй, я бы уточнил, что `данный сокет никем не читается` означает, что нет ни одного процесса, имеющего открытый на чтение дескриптор, связанный с этм сокетом. / Т.е. не читается -- это значит *в принципе* никто в системе в данный момент его *не может* читать. / А то это можно понять как -- никто не вызвал в этот момент read для сокета или никто давно не читал и какая-то очередь переполнилась...

Comment: По сути, сейчас клиентом является стандартный браузер... Он даёт запрос на скачивание файла серверу и он же (браузер) пытается считать этот файл ,как с какого-нибудь сайта... Механизм один и тотже... Получается, что где-то сервер делает что-то не то... Понять бы сейчас, что не так...

Comment: @avp, Вы правы, поправила.

Comment: @sitev_ru, а Вы сбросьте куда-нибудь (в pastebin, например) весь протокол обмена (что-то в виде текста C->S 200 байт :bla-bla S->C 50 байт ... C->S: ... и т.д. ), посмотрим файлик, подумаем

Comment: @sitev_ru, если Вы все-таки получаете сигнал SIGPIPE на строне демона, то причину искать надо на стороне клиента.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/pwYhJx7L - оказалось, что, например, картинки jpg читаются на ура, тот же файл переименовал в apk - работает как описано выше... клиент не может быть виноват - это стандартный браузер

Comment: @sitev_ru, в нете попадается информация, что стандартный загрузчик на Андроиде (особенно ниже 3.х) с ошибками скачивает файлы, и предлагается установить альтернативный браузер со встроенным менеджером загрузок, может Вам тоже этот подход попробовать?

Comment: Если я качаю с веб-сервера apache, то проблем нет никаких. А если через свой демон, он ошибка... Хочу уж добиться такого же результата стандартными средствами)

Comment: Выявил закономерность - ошибка возникает примерно после считывания 14 КБайт... плюс-минус... ))

Comment: http://pastebin.com/M6h4vnZ2 - логи работы демона

Comment: Вчитался в логи, смотрю, вначале браузер делает запрос такой:

Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate

А я ему не сжимаю ничего, а пересылаю как есть...

Он качает, через какое-то время сбрасывает и делает новый запрос:

Accept-Encoding: identity

Я ему передаю как есть и всё сразу нормально читает)... Архивировать gzip чтоли?

Comment: @sitev_ru, ну если браузер во время выкачивания проверяет, что именно он качает, и при несоответствии рубит соединение, то на другом конце Вы SIGPIPE и получите. Вероятно, не стоит просто так менять расширения передаваемого файла, либо отключить в браузере проверку типов, если есть такая возможность.

Answer (score 0):

Эта ошибка возникает на всех линуксах, при работе с сокетами. Лечится вызовом `signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);`

Comment: Что значит -- лечится? ТС же не жалуется, что у него демон рушится. SIG_IGN означает, что  если не установлен обработчик сигнала, то процесс не упадет, а следующий write()-то в этот сокет все равно вернет -1 и все равно сокет придется закрывать. Да и вопрос про другое.

Comment: Увидел знакомые слова, подсказал. Мозги не работают совершенно. У меня, давным давно, когда я начинал программировать под линуксом без игнорирования этого сигнала падал весь процесс.